# Session expired

Tags: java, web-applications, session-timeout

Welcome. I have a login filter that checks whether the current user session has not expired. The faces-config:

```
 <filter>
        <filter-name>filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>filter.LoginFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/protected/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping> 
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            1
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
        <location>/login.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
```

The filter applies only to pages in the folder protected. When the session expires, go to page login.xhtml. I have several sites without a folder protected, but the session on these pages also expires. Why?

Comment: That's not the *faces-config.xml* instead your *web.xml* file.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing in your `web.xml` that has a bearing on session lifetime is

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        1
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

which is setting the session timeout to one minute. It's immaterial whether you have a `Filter` set or not. Or, whether the user has logged into the site yet or not.

The `session` is global *for* the client and gets created even if the client hasn't logged in explicitly (with a username and password) yet. It's just that post-login you set something in the *already* created `session` object that authenticates the client as well.

So, when the `session` expires, it expires globally i.e. for all the pages of your web application; whether they are inside `/protected` or not doesn't matter.